# Azure API Management - Authorize Attribute

Tags: azure, authorize

I'm hosting my API in Azure and configured API Management for authentication and authorization.  Do I still need to include the [Authorize] attribute on my api controllers?  If so, what would I need in the Startup class to allow access when calling through Azure, but be unauthorized if call the endpoints directly?

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TestController : BaseController
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding from your question you can take up in this way.

1. Still go with [Authorize], as after hosting in APIm stil app need to authorize the user, post authentication.
2. Authentication will be there in startup.cs

   ```
   services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddJwtBearer(options =>
          {
              options.Authority = <<Pass your authority>>;
              options.Audience = <<Pass audience>>;
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
              {
                  ValidateIssuer = false
              };

          });
   ```
3. Use Validate `Jwt Inbound policy` in APIM.
4. But if the user is able to generate a required Bearer token then it should be able to access. If you want to restrict if it's not from APIM then you can check the `APIM subscription Key` in the header & can decline the user request.

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I am looking for.